# How to disable Azure Function Homepage?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

I have created Azure Function (Test URL: https://nparikhfunc.azurewebsites.net), how to disable homepage or replace it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To disable, add an app setting `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` with value `true`. Regarding changing the homepage this is not currently supported but see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/848#issuecomment-269803057) for the latest info.